# Is there a way to specify the home folder while opening the terminal with Java?

Tags: java, linux, macos, shell

It's quite easy to open the terminal on Mac with following code:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] cmd = {"/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm"}
runtime.exec(cmd);
```

> BobZhao@mac:~ > pwd
>  /Users/BobZ

My default home folder is ***/Users/BobZ*** and is there a way to specify one path while opening the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

There is an *exec* method taking three parameters , the third one is the working directory you want :

```
public Process exec(String command,String[] envp,File dir)
```